# Accessing a protected member

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm new to C++ and struggling to setup a proper class with private members and accessing them. Basically, I have a vector of Layers which make up a Stack.  I'd like to create a simple function which simply adds a layer to the stack.  I've tried to simplify this example to explain my problem.

```
// Stack.h
namespace NS {
    class Stack
    {
    public:
        Stack() {

        }
        virtual ~Stack() {

        }

        std::vector<Layer> const &getLayers() const;

        virtual Layer* AddLayer(TextureBase texture);

    protected:
        std::vector<Layer> _layers;
}
```

This is my cpp file

```
//Stack.cpp
namespace NS {

    std::vector<Layer> const &Stack::getLayers() const { 
        return _layers; 
    }

    Layer* Stack::AddLayer(TextureBase texture) {
        Layer* newLayer = new Layer();
        newLayer->setTexture(texture);

        std::vector<Layer> layerStack = Stack::getLayers();
        layerStack.push_back(*newLayer);

        return newLayer;
    }
}
```

In my main file I create the stack and then try to add the layer like this:

```
auto myStack = getStack();
myStack->AddLayer(myTexture);
```

However, when I place a breakpoint after this line, myStack doesn't contain any layers (the size is 0).  I can step through the AddLayer function and it does appear to add the Layer to the Stack... but perhaps it's not referencing the vector correctly.  Can anyone provide some guidance as to why this is occurring?

Comment: `auto myStack = getStack();` makes a copy, it does not deduce the reference.

Comment: So, how would I go about properly accessing the stack by reference?

Comment: You can probably use `auto & myStack = getStack();`, but you haven't shown what `getStack()` is. You have the same issue with `std::vector<Layer> layerStack = Stack::getLayers();`.

Comment: Please show us the main.cpp and where you are creating it. I'd guess (but don't have any evidence to back it up) that the stack created in 'getStack()' is going out of scope immediately.

Comment: Why was this question down voted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `layerStack` is a local copy of `_layers`:

```
std::vector<Layer> layerStack = Stack::getLayers();
```

You are pushing your new layer to this local copy, not to your data member. You need to take a reference to your data member instead:

```
std::vector<Layer>& layerStack = Stack::getLayers();
```

Alas, this won't compile because your `getLayers` function returns a `const` reference. You need to add a non-`const` counterpart:

```
std::vector<Layer>& getLayers();
```

Comment: I think this was the best example which now seems to work.  I changed my getter function to look like your last one (updating both the header and cpp file).  Then, I call the getter like this: `std::vector<Layer>& layerStack = Stack::getLayers();`  Then, I'm able to call `layerStack.push_back(*newLayer);` and it appears to add it to the stack.

Comment: @andyopayne Keep in mind that the other comments about you pushing a _copy_ of your layer are accurate. The layer returned from `AddLayer` is not the same as the layer in the `_layers`. You probably need to make `_layers` a `vector<unique_ptr<Layer>>` instead (safer than a raw pointer).

Comment: Also, FYI, you don't need to qualify the call to `getLayers` with `Stack::` from inside a member function of `Stack`.

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 issues you have to address.

1. `Layer* newLayer = new Layer()` will dynamically allocate a Layer object, but when you insert it into your vector, you dereference it, so you end up doing a `push_back` on a COPY of your `Layer` object. You could have just used `Layer newLayer = Layer()`, or if I understand your intent correctly a vector of Layer pointers:

```
vector<Layer*> _layers;
```

2. In order to be editable, your `getLayers()` function must NOT return a const-ref to the _layers vector. Change it to `std::vector& getLayers();`
3. Finally,  `std::vector layerStack = Stack::getLayers();` creates a COPY of the vector returned by `getLayers()`. Change it to  `std::vector& layerStack = Stack::getLayers()`

Comment: `Layer newLayer = Layer();` might as well just be `Layer newLayer;`.

Comment: Considering that `AddLayer()`is a member function of `Stack` it would be simpler to skip calling `Stack::GetLayers()` and directly call `_layer.push_back(newLayer)`

Comment: I didn't realize I could call _layers directly. Thanks.